# Value cannot be null. Parameter name: String in asp.net mvc C#

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am pretty new to asp.net mvc. I want to get the parameter string in my url

```
http://localhost/Item/ItemSpec/3431?dep=62&cat=129&tab=2
```

How can I get the value=3431?

I tried to used `HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString["id"]`, but it's not work. 3431 is the id of the item that display in my page, that's why I used ["id"].

Thanks you so much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `3431` is part of the *path* of the request, not part of the query string. You *could* use [`HttpRequest.Path`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.path.aspx) to get at the path, but MVC routing should allow you to simply write a controller method which accepts the ID as a parameter. I suggest you read up on [how to configure routing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668201.aspx). (Just searching for ASP.NET routing or MVC routing will give you *lots* of articles.)

Comment: Does it can do by regular expression or something else beside routing?

Comment: @titi - sure you could, but then you would have 2 problems

Comment: @titi: Potentially - but why would you want to? Routing solves this cleanly for you - why make things more complex?

Comment: @titi: Take the time (it's small amount of time anyway) to learn Asp.net MVC properly before you give it up by vehemently stating *it's too complex* or *it doesn't work*.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the default route is configured in Global.asax (`{controller}/{action}/{id}`) you could have your controller action take an id parameter and the default model binder will automatically set its value:

```
public ActionResult Foo(string id)
{
    ...
}
```

If you want to fetch this id value from some other portion of your code that does have access to an `HttpContext` you need to fetch it from the `RouteData`:

```
var id = HttpContext.Request.RequestContext.RouteData["id"];
```

`RouteData` is available in all standard MVC locations. In your example you have used the static `HttpContext.Current` property which is something that you should never use. I suspect that you are trying to fetch this id from a portion of your code where you are not supposed to have access to the HttpContext. So you'd better fetch this `id` using standard techniques and then pass it as parameter to other parts of your code.

Answer (score 1):

If Item is your controller, and ItemSpec is action, you can get the Id just by

```
public ActionResult ItemSpec(int id) { }
```

You routing have to be setup to:

```
context.MapRoute(
    "Default",
    "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index"  }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't changed your routing so it's still defined as it was when you created Asp.net MVC Web project then this should be one of your controllers:

```
public class ItemController : ControllerBase
{
    ...

    public ActionResult ItemSpec(int id, int dep, int cat, int tab)
    {
        // implementation that uses all four values
    }

    ...
}
```

This is of course just one of the actions in it. There may be others as well. Most likely the `Index` one that's generated by default and is also used by default routing...